# Implementing Secure Server-Level Authentication for Django Web Service on IIS with MS Power Automate

Tags: django, web-services, security, iis

I have a Django web service hosted on IIS (Internet Information Services) that is frequently invoked by Power Automate (formerly Microsoft Flow). However, I'm facing challenges when trying to integrate Power Automate with the Django web service using Windows Authentication.

The objective is to ensure that Power Automate can securely access the API endpoints of the Django web service, but at the same time, I want to avoid storing any plain text passwords on the server and disable Anonymous Authentication.

I'm seeking guidance from the Stack Overflow community on how to overcome these challenges and implement a secure solution for integrating Power Automate with the Django web service using Windows Authentication. Specifically, I'd like to understand:

- Configuring IIS for Windows Authentication: What are the necessary steps to enable and configure Windows Authentication in IIS to authenticate Power Automate requests?
- Credential management best practices: Since storing plain text passwords is not an option, what are the recommended methods for securely managing and authenticating with the Django web service without exposing sensitive information?
- Handling Power Automate integration: Are there any specific considerations or adjustments needed in the Django web service to seamlessly integrate with Power Automate using Windows Authentication?

Thank you for your time and assistance!

I tried to implement secure webservice on IIS without storing any plain text password

Comment: There are many approaches to integrate Power Automate with a Django web service. Why did you drop others (like OAuth) but Windows authentication?

Comment: @LexLi Thanks Lex. I want to a simplest way first.

Comment: Windows Authentication allows clients to authenticate using their Windows credentials, providing a seamless and secure integration. When users access the web service, their Windows credentials are used for authentication without storing plain text passwords. On the IIS server, you need to configure Windows Authentication for the Django web service.

Comment: Also, configure Power Automate to send Windows credentials when making requests to the Django web service. Instead of storing individual user credentials, you can use service accounts to authenticate with Django web services. This account will have the necessary permissions to perform the required operations. This way, you don't store user credentials on the server.